# How to cast object to Action<T>

Tags: c#, generics

I've created a simple message bus that queues and emits/publishes events.

I'm using StructureMap to locate the registered handlers (`Action<T>`) of the event but am not sure how to cast it from the object that StructureMap returns into an invoke-able action.

Since I can't cast to `Action<object>` I'm assuming that `Action<T>` is not covariant? Can this be done another way?

```
public class Bus
{
    private ConcurrentQueue<object> events = new ConcurrentQueue<object>();
    public void Queue<TEvent>(TEvent e)
    {
        events.Enqueue(e);
    }

    public void Emit()
    {
        object e;
        while (events.TryDequeue(out e))
        {
            var handlerType = typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(e.GetType());
            foreach (var handler in ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances(handlerType))
            {
                // how to invoke action?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if inside your `Queue` method you'd queue not events but rather the code which emits them?

```
private ConcurrentQueue<Action> handlers = new ConcurrentQueue<Action>();
public void Queue<TEvent>(TEvent e)
{
    handlers.Enqueue(new Action(() =>
    {
        foreach (var handler in GetHandlers<TEvent>())
        {
            handler(e);
        }    
    }));
}

public void Emit()
{
    Action act;
    while (handlers.TryDequeue(out act))
    {
        act();
    }
}

private IEnumerable<Action<TEvent>> GetHandlers<TEvent>()
{
    return ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances(typeof(Action<TEvent>>));
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The issue is that I don't have a type parameter at the time the events are handled. If you look at my code sample again you can see they are queued and then handled later.

Comment: Sorry, didn't spot that. I've re-written my answer.

Comment: I just arrived at the same conclusion. This certainly resolves any casting issues.

Answer (score 6):

> Since I can't cast to Action I'm assuming that Action is not covariant?

`Action<T>` is *contravariant* - which makes sense, because an `Action<object>` can be treated as an `Action<string>` (both can accept a `string` reference) but an `Action<string>` can't be treated as an `Action<object>` (what would you expect it to do if you provided it a non-string reference?).

The simplest way to invoke this is probably to just use [`Delegate.DynamicInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.dynamicinvoke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to be honest - another alternative would be to write a generic method and invoke it either with reflection or using `dynamic`.

Comment: Could I perhaps introduce my contravariant interface for handlers that allow the generic type to be downcasted? I tried `IHandle<in T>` but it won't let me downcast to `IHandle<object>`.

Comment: @BenFoster: Well no, precisely because it's contravariant and you're trying to use it covariantly. Have you tried either of the approaches I suggested?

Comment: I've tried `DynamicInvoke` which works but I read this has more overhead than `Invoke`. I suppose another option is to queue the *handling* of the event, this way I can avoid any casting issues e.g. `queue.Enqueue(() => Handle<TEvent>(e))`.

Comment: @BenFoster: Yes, `DynamicInvoke` will have a fair amount of overhead - but how much is performance an issue for you? The answer you've accepted seems like a good one though.

Comment: I'm not sure (without benchmarkings) but the events would be handled synchronously so performance is a factor. I think I'll stick with the accepted answer though as it is quite a nice solution.